# I'm trying to import Lotus Notes Structured Text as some data I can perform linq queries on

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, serialization

I"m not even really too sure how to approach this, but that's my question.  How to approach this:

I have many (10000s) of these examples and need to extract as much data as possible into various members/lists of a data type.  Since it's not JSON or XML I don't think I have deserialize options.  Maybe regex somehow into a user-defined class of data?

```
Status:  In Process
Prefix:  18-
PlantLoc:  Lewiston
Date:  08/10/2018
Department:  FT
Time:  08/10/2018 02:08:30 PM
StationID:  177
Fixture:  initialization 
Supervisor:  Da Mi
PMOnly:  
PartNo:  0735
SerialNum:  
FailedStep:  Validate/Validate firmware
Reason:  Script
OtherReason:  
Details:  Initalization failure 
Urgency:  Script Problem
Date_1:  08/10/2018
Time_1:  08/10/2018 04:24:06 PM
Date_2:  
Time_2:  
ProblemFound:  
SolutionCode:  
Solution:  8/14/2018  TSR  SSR 18-07121 was also entered.  8/14/2018 GAH. The 735 units with B1492-6 boards fail during Test Flash possibly due to a timing issue in the script.  These particular board types have 1GB of flash and take longer for the flash test.  I will need to contact TMESoftware to see if the WAIT time can be increased for the 735 units with B1492-6-XX boards.  8/14/2018 GAH.  Details:  https://jira.metro.ad.selinc.com/browse/MTEN-1814
ServiceTechHrs:  
ServiceEngHrs:  
DocHistory:  Assignee #1 xxxxx xxxxx assigned by Alex xxxxx on 08/10/2018,Request submitted by xxxxx on 08/10/2018,Request created by xxxxx Olander on 08/10/2018
Mailed:  1
CloseDate:  
HoldOn:  
HoldOff:  
Authors:  *
ISAuthors:  IS Notes Developers; LocalDomainAdmins; LocalDomainServers
MgrData:  
SaveOptions:  1
IniDate:  08/10/2018
IniTime:  08/10/2018 02:08:30 PM
MOT:  
RequestNum:  07011
Initiator:  xxxxx xxxxx
Notification:  LWS Flex Leaders
ServiceTech:  xxxxx xxxxx
ServiceEng:  
SolutionCode_1:  
FixtureCheck:  Stop
Solution_1:  8/14/2018  TSR  SSR 18-07121 was also entered.  8/14/2018 GAH. The 735 units with B1492-6 boards fail during Test Flash possibly due to a timing issue in the script.  These particular board types have 1GB of flash and take longer for the flash test.  I will need to contact TMESofre to see if the WAIT time can be increased for the 735 units with B1492-6-XX boards.  8/14/2018 GAH.  Details:  https://jira.metro.ad.com/browse/MTEN-1814
$Revisions:  08/10/2018 02:17:28 PM,08/10/2018 02:17:29 PM,08/10/2018 04:24:06 PM,08/10/2018 04:24:07 PM,08/13/2018 08:34:47 AM,08/14/2018 02:59:06 PM,08/14/2018 03:02:59 PM

SupDoc:  SSR 18-07121
```

This works, but how to add "only for Value="ServiceTech" && Key=named "Walter":

```
var bleh = SSRList.Where(x => x.ContainsKey("ServiceTechHrs"))                      
.Select(x => x["ServiceTechHrs"])                       
.Where(x => x != "")
.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x))
.Dump("Total All Tech Hours");
```

Comment: You don't even need regular expressions - just consume the data line by line, explode on the first colon to get a key-value pair, and then insert the data into your data store. Does your database use SQL? Indeed, these items could probably be stored in a normal relational database, unless Lotus gives you something specific you wish to use.

Comment: Instead of a class, you should probably use a `Dictionary` assuming the records aren't all identical.

Comment: @halfer - How to"explode on the first colon"?  What about "Solution_1:" which needs further processing fit into the dictionary scheme?

Comment: Well, _in general_, your data appears to be a set of key-value pairs, which can be inserted into a database using a script. Perhaps in most cases you can treat each value as a string, and the type of each column in your table(s) will determine if it is an integer, a float, a string, or a date (etc). However, that does not mean you can't do any pre-processing on selected keys. So for `Solution_1`, if this is an object, you could use a script to flatten the keys within to top level keys, or do some other processing before the insert.