# How to get data out of List<Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

I'm having trouble manipulating the `List<Dictionary<string,string>>> SSRList` to get data out of it easily. I've gotten this far:

```
var bleh = SSRList
    .Where(x => x.ContainsKey("ServiceTechHrs"))  //Scott Shauf total tech hours
    .Where(x => x.ContainsKey("ServiceTech") && x.ContainsValue("Scott Shauf"))
    .Select(x => x["ServiceTechHrs"])
    .Where(x => x != "")
    .Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x))
    .Dump("All Scott Shauf TechNumbers");
```

This answers how many hours scott worked total as a technician.

How would I answer "How many hours did Scott and Doug spend as either a technician or as an engineer?" I'm having difficulty with syntax that will allow me to ask lambda expressions... Along the same lines, I'm wondering how I could do a "GroupBy" on Dict Keys?

Comment: For this kind of queries, I think a `List<Dictionaty<string,string>>` is the wrong type to store the data. It would be much easier to work with dedicated classes.

Comment: Why `x.ContainsValue("Scott Shauf")` instead of `x["ServiceTech"] == "Scott Shauf"` as I assume that's the entry you want to check.  Otherwise any value could potential have his name, like if there's a supervisor entry.

Comment: I think you want `.Where(x => (x.ContainsKey("ServiceTech") && (x["ServiceTech"] == "Scott" || x["ServiceTech"] == "Doug")) || (x.ContainsKey("Engineer") && (x["Engineer"] == "Scott" || x["Engineer"] == "Doug")))`.   As for grouping you have two aspects here, keys existing and the value for that key, so it really depends on what exactly you want to group on because filtering on the key existing first then grouping on the value would make the most sense.

Comment: Also consider having an entry like "TypeOfJob" that's either Engineer or ServiceTech and another entry that is "Employee" name instead, and like @ZoharPeled said you'd be better off with custom classes instead.

Comment: You started asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51887318/861716). Then, when no answers came you chose to continue with `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` and started asking [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51904380/861716) following that track. But you took the wrong turn. You should have chosen a class having the keys as properties and the values as property values. That would make LINQ queries trivial. Now you always have to look for key/value pairs having (Key == x && Value == y).

Comment: I consider this question a duplicate of your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51887318/861716), because it's yet another question on how to query `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

Comment: There is nothing really wrong with what you have done here, for GroupBy all you have to know is you get a `Pair<>` with the group-by key and the `List<>` of group members.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, using a `Dictionary<string, string>` to represent some structured type rids you of all the beauty of LINQ. If however you have to go down that road for some (questionable) design reasons, going strongly typed as soon as possible would bring it back.

Seems you' like to work with something like

```
public interface ITechnician
{
    string ServiceTech { get; }
    double ServiceTechHours { get; } // or should it be TimeSpan?
}
```

I'd write some code to do the dirty work:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ITechnician> OfTypeTechnician(this IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> records)
    {
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            if (!record.TryGetValue("ServiceTech", out var serviceTech)) continue;
            if (!record.TryGetValue("ServiceTechHrs", out var serviceTechHrsStr) || !double.TryParse(serviceTechHrsStr, out var serviceTechHrs)) continue;
            yield return new Technician { ServiceTech = serviceTech, ServiceTechHours = serviceTechHrs };
        }
    }

    private class Technician : ITechnician
    {
        public string ServiceTech { get; set; }
        public double ServiceTechHours { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Rest is easy:

```
var records = new[]
{
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ServiceTech", "Scott Shouf"}, { "ServiceTechHrs", "4711" } },
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ServiceTech", "Scott Shouf"}, { "ServiceTechHrs", "0815" } },
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ServiceTech", "Scott Shouf"}, { "ServiceTechHrs", "not convertible to double" } },
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ServiceTech", "Someone Else"}, { "ServiceTechHrs", "42" } },
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Animal", "Giraffe" } }
};

var allScottShaufTechNumbers = records
    .OfTypeTechnician()
    .Where(t => t.ServiceTech == "Scott Shouf")
    .Sum(t => t.ServiceTechHours);
// 5526
```